Filter list view date field by all entries that are NOT BLANK
I have a field that is either blank or has a specific date entered. I want to create a view that shows all the list items that are NOT Blank.
In the filter list, I can select (empty) or hundreds of specific dates. I want all existing and future dates, just not the blank ones. Is this possible?

If you want to hide (Empty) option from date column filtering pane, you have to apply the filter on your SharePoint list view.
You can apply filter from list view settings like (from classic list view settings page):

Documentation: Use filtering to modify a SharePoint list views.
Output:
Before:

After:

